# Customizing torus diagram in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

I'm trying to produce a nice torus diagram to illustrate its parametrization. I have this:

[image]

but would like to have this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

There's a list of things I can't figure out how to do:

1. Move axis labels closer to axes and reverse `y` axis.
2. Bring *positive* parts of `x` and `z` axes to foreground.
3. Add major and minor radii `a` and `b` as illustrated.
4. Crop white space above and to the right.

Here's the current code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis equal image,
        xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$,
        axis lines=middle,
        xmax=18,ymax=20,zmax=5,
        ticks=none,
        clip bounding box=upper bound,
        colormap/blackwhite]

        \addplot3[domain=0:360,y domain=0:320, samples=20,surf,z buffer=sort]
            ({(12 + 3 * cos(x)) * cos(y)} ,
            {(12 + 3 * cos(x)) * sin(y)},
            {3 * sin(x)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that in your second picture, the axes dont seem right handed.

Comment: use the axis coordinate system to plot minor and major radii. Add this after the `\addplot` command `\draw [thick, blue] (axis cs: 0,0,0) -- (axis cs: 12,0,0);
        \draw [thick, red] (axis cs: 12,0,0) -- (axis cs: 12,0,3);`

Comment: Since Tikz/PGF plots doesn't have *real 3D™*, it will be better to re draw the X and Z axes using the same axis coordinate convention *after* the `\addplot` command just like the radii were drawn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use axis coordinate systems to put regular tikz commands in the pgfplot axes.
To bring the axes to foreground, I used the same method to *fake* the axes. This is **not** a general solution for other plots.

If you reverse the y axis, the system will not be right handed, and people generally expect axes to be right handed. It is better to bring the x axis to the front and y axis to the right side of the picture (z axis will remain pointed up).

[image: torus]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis equal image,
        axis lines=middle,
        xmax=18,ymax=20,zmax=5,
        ticks=none,
        clip bounding box=upper bound,
        colormap/blackwhite]

        \addplot3[domain=0:360,y domain=0:320, samples=40,surf,z buffer=sort]
            ({(12 + 3 * cos(x)) * cos(y)} ,
            {(12 + 3 * cos(x)) * sin(y)},
            {3 * sin(x)});
        %use axis coordinate system to draw the radii
        \draw [thick, blue] (axis cs: 0,0,0) -- node [yshift=0.5em]{$a$} (axis cs: 12,0,0);
        \draw [thick, red] (axis cs: 12,0,0) -- node [xshift=0.5em]{$b$}(axis cs: 12,0,3);

        %use axis coordinate system to draw FAKE x, y and z axes
        \draw [-latex]  (axis cs: 0,0,0) -- node [pos=0.9, xshift=0.5em]{$z$}(axis cs: 0,0,10);
        \draw [-latex]  (axis cs: 0,-15,0) --
         node [pos=0.9, xshift=-1em, yshift=0.5em]{$y$}(axis cs: 0,-20,0);
        \draw (axis cs: 0,0,0) -- (axis cs: 0,9,0);
        \draw (axis cs: 0,0,0) -- (axis cs: -9,0,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks great! Switching `x` and `y` wouldn't be a problem. (By the way, the `x` axis seems to be unlabeled in your solution.)

Comment: I think it may be better you wait a few more hours before accepting this as an answer, as someone with more conversant with pgf plots may propose a better answer; especially if you plan on expanding this to different types of surfaces.

Comment: I don't at present, but if you think a more elegant solution is possible, then that might still be a good idea.